# OnClick listener to list items

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm creating a multiple choice quiz and I'm having a difficult time with implementing an onClick listener.

I've tried to use jQuery to create an alert when a button is choice but that seems not to be working.

Could someone take a look at why it's not being triggered? Also, how can I pass in the content of the list item?

```
<body>
  <div class="central-area" id="central-area">
    <div class="main multiple-choice">
      <div class="question-row row column">
        <div id="questionText" class="question-text">to be</div>
      </div>
      <div class="hint row column"> <span class="hint-text">Select the correct <strong>French</strong> for the <strong>English</strong> above:</span> </div>
      <ol id="choices" class="choices ">
        <li class="choice " id="0"><span class="val">prêter</span><span class="marking-icon "></span></li>
        <li class="choice " id="1"><span class="val">vêtir</span><span class="marking-icon "></span></li>
        <li class="choice " id="2"><span class="val">être</span><span class="marking-icon "></span></li>
        <li class="choice " id="3"><span class="val">tirer</span><span class="marking-icon "></span></li>
      </ol>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Javascript:

```
function guess(choice) {
  if (choice === "être") {
    alert("Correct");
    //Add correct class to chosen button
  } else {
    alert("Incorrect");
    //Add incorrect class to chosen button
    //Time delay, then add correct class to correct button
  }
}

$( "li" ).click(function() {
  alert( "Handler for .click() called." );
  // guess(choice);
});
```

Here's a duplicate of the current situation: https://jsfiddle.net/a5j4zncv/16/

Comment: I think instead of using `list (li)` for creating choice elements , it would be better to do it using `radio` or `checkbox`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go. 
you have to select the text from each li and then compare it.
Also as Milan Chheda pointed, you have to include the JQ library.

```js
function guess(choice) {
  var ch = $(choice).text();
  if (ch == "être") {
    alert("Correct");
    //Add correct class to chosen button
  } else {
    alert("Incorrect");
    //Add incorrect class to chosen button
    //Time delay, then add correct class to correct button
  }
}

$( "#choices li" ).click(function() {
    guess(this);
  //alert( "Handler for .click() called." );
  // guess(choice);
});
```

```css
.choice:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.choice.correct {
  color: green;
}

.choice.incorrect {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div class="central-area" id="central-area">
    <div class="main multiple-choice">
      <div class="question-row row column">
        <div id="questionText" class="question-text">to be</div>
      </div>
      <div class="hint row column"> <span class="hint-text">Select the correct <strong>French</strong> for the <strong>English</strong> above:</span> </div>
      <ol id="choices" class="choices ">
        <li class="choice " id="0"><span class="val ">prêter</span><span class="marking-icon"></span></li>
        <li class="choice " id="1"><span class="val ">vêtir</span><span class="marking-icon"></span></li>
        <li class="choice " id="2"><span class="val ">être</span><span class="marking-icon"></span></li>
        <li class="choice " id="3"><span class="val ">tirer</span><span class="marking-icon"></span></li>
      </ol>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't added the JQuery library:

```js
function guess(choice) {
  if (choice === "être") {
    alert("Correct");
    //Add correct class to chosen button
  } else {
    alert("Incorrect");
    //Add incorrect class to chosen button
    //Time delay, then add correct class to correct button
  }
}

$("li").on('click', function() {
  alert("Handler for .click() called.");
  guess($(this).text());
});
```

```css
.choice:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.choice.correct {
  color: green;
}

.choice.incorrect {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div class="central-area" id="central-area">
    <div class="main multiple-choice">
      <div class="question-row row column">
        <div id="questionText" class="question-text">to be</div>
      </div>
      <div class="hint row column"> <span class="hint-text">Select the correct <strong>French</strong> for the <strong>English</strong> above:</span> </div>
      <ol id="choices" class="choices ">
        <li class="choice " id="0"><span class="val ">prêter</span><span class="marking-icon"></span></li>
        <li class="choice " id="1"><span class="val ">vêtir</span><span class="marking-icon"></span></li>
        <li class="choice " id="2"><span class="val ">être</span><span class="marking-icon"></span></li>
        <li class="choice " id="3"><span class="val ">tirer</span><span class="marking-icon"></span></li>
      </ol>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```